# Delay in script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 2 scripts, 1 for player movement and 2nd one for his powers and if the player presses "q" he uses his power and I put a delay into 2nd script to prevent him from pressing it nonstop. But whole game frezes and I would like to know if there is a ways to not have app frozen but just add cool down on this power.

Here is the code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;   

public class SuperPower1 : MonoBehaviour
{   
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public float forwardForce = 2000f;  // Variable that determines the forward force
    bool Break;
    void FixedUpdate()
    {   
        //Break
        {
            if (Input.GetKey("q"))
            {
                Break = true;
                int milliseconds = 2000;
                Thread.Sleep(milliseconds);
            }
            else
            {
                Break = false;
            }
        }
        if (Break == true)
        {
            rb.AddForce(0, 0, 500f * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else
        {
            rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated by @Draco18s, since your Unity game runs in one thread only, `Thread.sleep` will pause your **whole** game. Here is a simple script you can try. I haven't tested it, but you will get the idea ;)

```
public Rigidbody rb;
public float forwardForce = 2000f;
public float bonusDuration = 2.0f;   
private float endBonusTime = 0 ;

void FixedUpdate()
{   
    if ( endBonusTime < Time.time )
    {
        if( Input.GetKeyDown("q") )
            endBonusTime = Time.time + bonusDuration ;
        else   
           rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime);            
    }
    if (endBonusTime >= Time.time ) // Don't put "else if"
    {
        rb.AddForce(0, 0, 500f * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

---

If you want to put a cooldown to this, try the following script :

```
public Rigidbody rb;
public float forwardForce = 2f;
public float bonusDuration = 2.0f;   
private float endBonusTime = 0 ;
private float cooldown = 5.0f;

void FixedUpdate()
{   
    if ( endBonusTime < Time.time + cooldown && Input.GetKeyDown("q") )
    {
        endBonusTime = Time.time + bonusDuration ;
    }
    else if ( endBonusTime < Time.time )
    {
        rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    if (endBonusTime >= Time.time ) // Don't put "else if"
    {
        rb.AddForce(0, 0, 1 * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: *`Thread.sleep is not designed to work inside Unity`* Er...no. `Thread.sleep` is doing exactly what it was designed to do and this (unwanted) behavior is identical in *any* single-threaded application. I've had to tell Minecraft modders to stop using `Thread.sleep` for the exact same reason: this is not what it was designed to do. Unity *can* spawn child threads and `Thread.sleep` in those child threads (used correctly) does exactly what it was designed to do: pause the thread. There is nothing wrong with `Thread.sleep` or Unity, but rather it is being used incorrectly.

Comment: _`There is nothing wrong with Thread.sleep or Unity, but rather it is being used incorrectly`_ Yes, you are right, this is what I wanted to say

Comment: Thank you now I am  trying to prevent player from using it nonstop

Comment: @David : Check my updated answer. Don't forget to accept if my answer solved your problem ;)

Comment: @Hellium Thank you, you solved my problem. Huge thanks to you. I can now carry on with learning :)

Answer (score 3):

`Thread.sleep` is never the answer to "I want to delay something" because `Thread.sleep` causes *the program to become unresponsive.*

If you wan to delay an action, there's 3 things you can do:

1. create a timer variable and increment it during `Update()` by `Time.deltaTime` until the desired duration has elaspsed
2. [use a coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html)
3. use a tween engine and execute the delayed code in the tween's `onComplete` handler.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will take closer look at what you suggested to me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know `Unity` code, so this might have to be converted a little, but in normal `C#` code you could just have a variable that defines when the power-up is allowed. This way, when the user uses a power, you update the value to the current time plus the amount of time you want to wait. Then you just check that variable against the current time before granting the power:

```
private float nextAllowedPowerUpTime = 0;

void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (Input.GetKey("q") && Time.time >= nextAllowedPowerUpTime)
    {
        rb.AddForce(0, 0, 500f * Time.deltaTime);

        // Set the next allowed power-up time to the current time plus two seconds
        nextAllowedPowerUpTime = Time.time + 2;
    }
    else
    {
        rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: This will probably work for the most part. However, rather than using `DateTime.Now`, use `Time.time`: we don't care that it's "Monday May 30th, 2017 at 11:50am" we only care about how long its been since the application started, and adding 2 seconds to that is easy: `Time.time + 2`

Comment: Thanks @Draco18s. I updated the answer. One of these days I have to play with `Unity`...

Comment: Unity is awesome. I don't find nearly as much pleasure in programming almost anything else (although modding Minecraft is comparable and I really do like Eclipse as an IDE, but VS is much better than most other IDEs I've had the displeasure of using). Try blocking out, say, four hours on a Saturday to fooling around with it.